# format function justify rstudio not working properly

Tags: r, format, justify

I'm trying to format a column from a data frame in rstudio and i'm having some issues,

dataframe name = formattest2
column name = kW

I want numbers on this column with this format, 1,123,459.000 aligned to centre but is not working. This is how I'm trying:

```
format(formattest2$kW, big.mark = ",", justify = "centre")
```

do you have any idea on how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: *"Align to center"* is completely relative. Alignment is based on each string and some overall width, so since formatting a number with commas does not include any whitespace on either side, alignment within each string is meaningless. Where do you want to center it? Is this for some report? I think it would help to know a little bit larger picture here to be able to help you.

Comment: @r2evans:  the `format()` function does include a `justify` argument.  The problem is that it is only used for character vectors.  To use it on numbers, you'd need to format the numbers to get commas, strip off the blanks, and reformat to justify.

Comment: @user2554330 good points, I made an assumption ... thanks. (An example to prove your point and disprove some of my assumptions: `format(c(1, 1000, 1e8), justify="right", big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)`.)

Comment: Daniel, *"but it is not working"* is not very helpful. Can you provide a sample of `formattest2$kW` that shows the not-working-ness that you see?

Comment: @r2evans I mean when I open the dataframe numbers in column are not aligned to center. I just added a picture of how it looks.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working normally, but this worked for me: `format(trimws(format(c(50.89, 273.88, 273663.03, 8011.945, 1210.755, 4645), big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE, nsmall = 3)), justify = "centre")`